# SaxonJS emits superfulous namespace attributes

Tags: xml-namespaces, saxon, saxon-js

When using SaxonJS, I am able to verify that it produces the same output as Saxon, with one caveat. It appears that SaxonJS will emit namespace attributes for every element, even when they are not needed. I tried adjusting `exclude-result-prefixes`, but this had no effect.

SaxonJS 1.2.0 Output

```xml
<CastVoteRecordReport xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">
    <CVR xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">
        <BallotStyleId xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">_01-0052-01</BallotStyleId>
        <CreatingDeviceId xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">rd</CreatingDeviceId>
        <CurrentSnapshotId xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">i__a_aaaaaago</CurrentSnapshotId>
        <CVRSnapshot xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd" ObjectId="i__a_aaaaaago">
            <CVRContest xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">
                <ContestId xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">_1GO</ContestId>
                <Undervotes xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd">1</Undervotes>
            </CVRContest>
...
```

Saxon-EE version 9.8.0.12 output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CastVoteRecordReport xmlns="NIST_V0_cast_vote_records.xsd"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <CVR>
      <BallotStyleId>_01-0052-01</BallotStyleId>
      <CreatingDeviceId>rd</CreatingDeviceId>
      <CurrentSnapshotId>i__a_aaaaaago</CurrentSnapshotId>
      <CVRSnapshot ObjectId="i__a_aaaaaago">
         <CVRContest>
            <ContestId>_1GO</ContestId>
            <Undervotes>1</Undervotes>
         </CVRContest>
...
```

The callback on SaxonJS.Transform is

```js
var transformCallback = (fragment: DocumentFragment) => {
            // have to convert to string?
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(fragment.cloneNode(true));
            // replace existing output content
            that.outputText(div.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon-JS 1.2.0 does not have a (complete, conformant) serializer, so the question arises, how are you producing the lexical XML output shown in your question?

In terms of the XDM data model, the XML and XSI namespaces should indeed be in scope on every element in the result tree; a good serializer will eliminate namespaces that are redundant. So this is all a question about how the result tree is being serialized.

(Note, Saxon-JS 2.0, which is the final stages of testing, will have a full serializer.)

Comment: I think that basically, Saxon-JS is constructing the DOM tree that's the closest approximation to the way the XDM model is defined in the XSLT specs -- which includes copies of inherited namespaces -- and it's relying on the serializer to eliminate the redundancy; but this serializer isn't doing so. Saxon-JS 2 should improve this. (Talk to Saxonica offline if you're interested in beta-testing a pre-release).

Comment: Does Saxon-JS 2.0 improve this situation?

Comment: Can't really tell without more information about what you are doing and how you are producing that output. The whole way result trees are constructed has changed, so it's very likely that the situation will be different.